# Compare CSV files and print results using Python

Tags: python, csv, compare

I'm looking to compare the values of (spelling of country names) two csv files and print the names of countries that had no match.  I am conducting spatial analysis on two datasets that have country names and I'm receiving inaccurate results, which I believe is stemming from the misspelling of country names.  I extracted the country names and saved them to two different CSV files for comparison. I've looked at several other examples on this site (many looking to compare several columns and execute a variety of other functions) and have not been successful in manipulating the code.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some representative sample of the input data (and desired output).

Comment: The input data is simple.  Both CVS files have one column (country names).  The data has been extracted from spatial datasets (shapefiles) and saved to CSV files to compare differences.  My spatial analysis are yield inaccurate results, which I believe is stemming from minute differences in spelling of names.  So, looking to identify country names that have no match.

Comment: @dchaboya, you'd better update initial question body when added additional info

Comment: And what have you tried to identify - say for instance, "Kenya" is "Kenyah" - or I could make up all sorts of others - how close is a match, are you using the ISO codes etc... so that once data is standardised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick stab at this:

```
import requests
import bs4     # the 'beautifulsoup4' module
import pickle

# find an 'all the countries' listing
url = "http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/countries_of_the_world.htm"
r   = requests.get(url)
bs  = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)

# grab all table rows
rows = [
    [cell.text.strip() for cell in row.findAll('td')]
    for row in bs.findAll('tr')
]
# filter for just the rows containing country-name data
rows = [row[1:] for row in rows if len(row) == 4]

# create a look-up table
country = {}
for en,fr,lo in rows:
    country[en] = en
    country[fr] = en
    country[lo] = en

# and store it for later use
with open('country.dat', 'wb') as outf:
    pickle.dump(country, outf)
```

We now have a dict which takes a variety of country spellings and returns the canonical English name for each. Depending on your data, you may wish to extend this to include ISO country abbreviations etc.

For spellings not in the dict, we can search for close alternatives:

```
import difflib

def possible_countries(c):
    res = difflib.get_close_matches(c, country.keys(), cutoff=0.5)
    return sorted(set(country[r] for r in res))
```

We can use this to work through your .csv files, prompting for the appropriate replacement:

```
import sys
import pickle
import csv

def main(csvfname):
    # get existing country data
    with open('country.dat', 'rb') as inf:
        country = pickle.load(inf)

    # get unique country names from your csv file
    with open(csvfname, 'rb') as inf:
        data = sorted(set(row[0] for row in csv.reader(inf)))

    for c in data:
        if c not in country:
            print('"{}" not found'.format(c))
            sugg = possible_countries(c)
            if sugg:
                print('Suggested replacements:\n  {}'.format('\n  '.join(sugg)))
            else:
                print('(no suggestions)')
            repl = raw_input('Enter replacement value (or <Enter> for none): ').strip()
            if repl:
                country[c] = repl

    # re-save country data
    with open('country.dat', 'wb') as outf:
        pickle.dump(country, outf)

if __name__=="__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        main(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        print('Usage: python fix_countries.py csvfname')
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can use

```
diff -u file1 file2
```

or any other file-comparison tool.
If not - please specify more details about input files.